# Begin / End undo group in XCTest / App causing odd behaviour

Tags: ios, testing, core-data, xctest, nsundomanager

Test set up:

```
// Create a clean context for this test.
NSManagedObjectContext *cleanContext = [MyContextManager sharedInstance] newMOC];

// Create a core data object.
MyCoreDataObject *myObject = [MyCoreDataObject insertNewObjectInMoc:cleanContext];
myObject.name = @"Test Name 1";

// Create an undo manager - set on the context.
cleanContext.undoManager = [NSUndoManager new];
// Turn off automatic grouping
cleanContext.undoManager.groupsByEvent = NO;
[cleanContext.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];

myObject.name = @"Test Name 2";

XCTAssertEqualObjects(myObject.name, @"Test Name 2", @"Setting name failed");

// End undo grouping
[cleanContext.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
// Undo the group that has just been created
[cleanContext.undoManager undoNestedGroup];

 XCTAssertEqualObjects(myObject.name, @"Test Name 1", @"Undo failed");
```

I see that the undo manager has a private stack of invocations I can access via `[cleanContext.undoManager performSelector:@selector(_undoStack)]` When looking at it even though I've turned off group by events there are new undo groupings that I haven't added.

This causes a lot of pain - errors such as `NSUndoManager is in invalid state` occur even though I correctly manage beginning and ending undo groups.

Does setting attributes on a core data object automatically add them irrespective of the group by events settings?

Has anyone managed to create a stable undo functionality using the built in undo manager?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see all your code, but if you're calling `undo()` in the test case, it will undo **everything** in your method so far. *(actually a good thing to test for)*

Each run loop creates its own *undo group*. The test method is within that run loop. Calling `undo()` will close that group, then undo everything.

You want to invoke `undoNestedGroup()` if you are trying to test the undo functionality. (my example is in Swift, but straightforward)

```
func testInsertUndo() {

  doc.undoManager?.beginUndoGrouping()
  let r1 = doc.createRegion("testRegion1")
  doc.undoManager?.endUndoGrouping()

  doc.undoManager?.beginUndoGrouping()
  doc.createRegion("testRegion2")
  doc.undoManager?.endUndoGrouping()

  // undo() will close surrounding run-loop undo group and then undo the whole thing
  doc.undoManager?.undoNestedGroup()
  XCTAssert(doc.regionCount == 1, "undo should remove last region \(doc.regionCount) != 1")

  for (index, r) in doc.regionEnumerator {
    XCTAssert(index == 0 && r === r1, "first region remains")
  }
}
```

Comment: I have called `undoNestedGroup` not `undo` so not sure that is the reason tbh. I was seeing weird grouping of events on the `undoStack`. This question is rather old, I'll have a go at using your swift implementation and see if I can get things working. A few questions, what is `doc` in your answer? Is it a managed object context? Also how can you determine when a particular run-loop will start / end?

Comment: `doc` is a custom subclass of `NSDocument`, basically a data object being managed in the Document-style app - it saves itself to a file format (no Core Data)

Comment: not sure of the internals of the XCTest framework, but they likely are invoking each test case from the run loop, so each method will be within it's own undoManager grouping. you can't really control that. in a UI interactive case, you are guaranteed that the user actions are arriving from there, so you have a fresh invocation from the run loop (and fresh undoManager grouping) for any user action. since we're simulating multiple user actions in one test case, we have to act differently